# How to set DriftOptionBlockDataLoss to false in SQL Change Automation VSTS release plugin

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, devops, redgate, readyroll

I'm running the latest SQL change automation vsts plugin. I added a new migration script doing the following

```
ALTER my_table ADD [description] varchar(max) NULL
```

When the release is been deployed i got the following error

`System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: An unhandled error occurred: RedGate.Versioning.Engine.Api.Exceptions.FileException: Drift analysis: These changes will NOT be applied because DriftOptionBlockDataLoss=True (see 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\DLM Automation\5dyfpy0w.ary\artifacts\SQL.Database.Migration_Database_DriftSyncScript.sql' for details). Changes have been detected that could result in data loss for the following table object(s): [dbo].[my_table].`

I know how to disable the DriftOptionBlockDataLoss using the MSBuild way but not in the vsts release plugin.

Also a question here, why adding a null column will raise the data loss error? I'm just adding a null column

Thank you all for any help provided.

Comment: Are you using this 3rd-party VSTS extension [SQL Change Automation: Release](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redgatesoftware.redgateDlmAutomationRelease) Seems the issue should more related to the extension, you could ask help in their official product support page-- https://productsupport.red-gate.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Please see [section 4](https://documentation.red-gate.com/rr1/continuous-integration) "Drift report and drift correction script" where `DriftOptionBlockDataLoss`, `DriftOptionDropMissingObjects`, and `DBReSyncOnBuild` params are configured.

Related thread: [Readyroll : Getting Error While Build using VSTS : Drift analysis: These changes will NOT be applied because DriftOptionBlockDataLoss=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55793706/readyroll-getting-error-while-build-using-vsts-drift-analysis-these-changes)