# Readyroll : Getting Error While Build using VSTS : Drift analysis: These changes will NOT be applied because DriftOptionBlockDataLoss=True

Tags: sql, visual-studio, azure-devops, redgate, readyroll

Some of the scripts were migrate manually without using readyroll script. Now any new push to dev branch fails with following error :

> DB\DB.sqlproj(0,0): Error : Drift analysis: These changes will NOT be applied because DriftOptionBlockDataLoss=True (see 'obj\Release\DB_ReSync.sql' for details). Changes have been detected that could result in data loss for the following table object(s):  dbo.Info.
>
> Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Same works fine on local but fails in the build created in VSTS.
What needs to be done for successful build ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using ReadyRoll Core and not the Pro edition as this functionality is part of the Pro edition of the VSTS extension. Please see the Red Gate documentation pertaining to ReadyRoll and the [Diff Report and diff correct script](https://documentation.red-gate.com/rr1/continuous-integration) (Section 4), where this param `DriftOptionBlockDataLoss` and other related params `DriftOptionDropMissingObjects` are established in the build pipeline.

[image: Section 4 - Diff Report and diff correction script]